# New Coder troubleshooting TypeError

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have been testing the code as I create it and it has been working great until I added my main function when my second function no longer can read property 'getId' of undefined.

I understand this means there is a gap somewhere but troubleshooting this is more than I can figure out how to do. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. I am just having trouble understanding why this segment would work fine and now it is throwing this typeError.

Here is my script-

```js
var ssID = "1DAHhRWq42bMz3xydqtgcDtJUhzTgA7HyN7AnX2osEec";
var formID = "1D-r1QnbN79ndIZdKHCJiD7n2rj_Qb6Lol9affPePakM";

var wsCode = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("Code");
var form = FormApp.openById(formID);

function main(){

    var labels = wsCode.getRange(1, 1,1,wsCode.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

    labels.forEach(function(label,a){

    var options = wsCode
    .getRange(3, a+1,wsCode.getLastRow()-1,1)
    .getValues()
    .map(function(o) {return o[0] });
   updateDropdownUsingTitle(label,options)
  });
}

function updateDropdownUsingTitle(title,values) {

    var items = form.getItems();
    var titles = items.map(function(item){
    return item.getTitle()
  });

    var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
    var item = items[pos];
    var itemID = item.getId();


    updateDropdown(itemID,values)

}


function updateDropdown(id,values) {

    var item = form.getItemById(id);

    item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Check your Scope

Change the second function from this:

```js
function updateDropdownUsingTitle(title,values) {

    var items = form.getItems();
    var titles = items.map(function(item){
    return item.getTitle()
  });

    var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
    var item = items[pos];
    var itemID = item.getId();


    updateDropdown(itemID,values)

}
```

To this:

```js
function updateDropdownUsingTitle(title,values) {
    var items = form.getItems();
    var titles = items.map(function(item){
        var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
        var item = items[pos];
        var itemID = item.getId();
        updateDropdown(itemID,values)
        return item.getTitle()
    });
}
```

The line `var itemID = item.getId();` was trying to call a variable defined in the scope of the `map` block, which ended before it. So this is why the variable `item` seems not to exist.

On another note, I am not sure why you are using `map` in this case. But without know more context, and having a sample project to test on my account, I can't troubleshoot further. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for a good article on how to provide this.

If this doesn't work, then try using `Logger.log()` to log the variables at all stages to track their values, or use the inbuilt debugger in the script editor.

#### References

- [Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)
- [Apps Script Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)